Filter data using multiple thresholds across single column summing other column
I have a dataframe with two columns (speed and distance) and a list of speed thresholds. For each speed threshold, I want to sum the distance travelled above the speed threshold. In reality I have a large dataset I want to apply this to and I am unable to come up with a quick solution.
I have included an example dataframe below. The expected outcome from that dataframe would be the following, ideally shown in a dataframe with threshold and distance covered.
The solution should generalise well to a large dataframe.



7 = 267, > 8 = 240, > 9 = 220, > 10 188, > 11 = 181, > 12 = 173



data = [(7,4), (8,5), (9,6), (10,7), (11,8), (7,9), (9,10), (14,11), (4,12), (16,13), (7,14), (8,15), (9,16), (2,17), (12,18), (14,19), (16,20), (24,21), (25,22), (6,23), (27,24), (28,25)]
columns = ["speed", "distance"]
thresholds = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)


You can do this with a case-when column expression and grouping with a list comprehension.
I would prefer this for large datasets over, say, cross-joining the dataframe with the thresholds.
Solution:
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def sum_if_greater_than_by(sum_col, by_col, threshold):
    cond_expr = F.when(F.col(by_col)>=threshold, F.col(sum_col)).otherwise(F.lit(0))
    return F.sum(cond_expr)

df_agg = df.groupBy().agg(*[sum_if_greater_than_by('distance', 'speed', threshold).alias(f">={threshold}") for threshold in thresholds])

Result:
The result is a dataframe:
df_agg.show()

+---+---+---+----+----+----+
|>=7|>=8|>=9|>=10|>=11|>=12|
+---+---+---+----+----+----+
|267|240|220| 188| 181| 173|
+---+---+---+----+----+----+


you can then also unpivot/melt the dataframe so that you have one row for each threshold: df_agg.melt(ids=[], values=df_agg.columns, valueColumnName='distance', variableColumnName='threshold').

This is great. Worked under 2 minutes for 61 thresholds.

One option is to create a view from the dataframe and execute a SQL statement for each element of the list.
I'm not sure if you are looking for the result as a string or some other form. Since this is executed sequentially, the speed of this will really depend on the length of the list and not so much on the size of the dataframe/dataset.
If you want it even faster, we can try a multithreaded approach.
data = [(7,4), (8,5), (9,6), (10,7), (11,8), (7,9), (9,10), (14,11), (4,12), (16,13), (7,14), (8,15), (9,16), (2,17), (12,18), (14,19), (16,20), (24,21), (25,22), (6,23), (27,24), (28,25)]
columns = ["speed", "distance"]
thresholds = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("testvw1")

output = ""
seq = 0
for i in thresholds:
    seq = seq + 1 
    output = output + f"> {i} = "
    x = spark.sql(f"select sum(distance) as SUM from testvw1 WHERE speed >= {i}")
    sum = (x.first()['SUM'])
    output = output + str(sum)
    if seq < len(thresholds):
        output = output + ","
print(output)

UPDATE
If you do not want to do things in a loop and want to use the power of databricks sql, you can use the below approach.
First create temporary views with your input dataset and your threshold dataset.
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

data = [(7,4), (8,5), (9,6), (10,7), (11,8), (7,9), (9,10), (14,11), (4,12), (16,13), (7,14), (8,15), (9,16), (2,17), (12,18), (14,19), (16,20), (24,21), (25,22), (6,23), (27,24), (28,25)]
columns = ["speed", "distance"]
thresholds = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("testvw1")

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(thresholds, IntegerType())
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("threshold")

Now do a crossjoin between the 2
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW v_crossjoin 
    AS 
    SELECT speed, distance, value as threshold FROM testvw1 CROSS JOIN threshold;

Finally you can do a select with a group by to get the necessary information.
%sql
select  threshold , sum(distance) as SUM from v_crossjoin where speed >= threshold group by threshold ; 


Thanks for your suggestion, but I think I'm looking for a solution without a loop. On the large dataframe I have with only 3 thresholds, the execution time is 6 mins, and I would like to have 40+ thresholds.

Check out my update in my existing answer.
